# Page re-renders on collection update

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am making a simple multiple user playlist application. I have one client watching the stream of videos, and in another I am trying to add a video to that playlist. The video adds to the playlist correctly, but when the update happens the page re renders and the video restarts on the client that is just watching. I am trying to get it so that when other users add videos to the playlist, it continues to play for all who are watching it.

On the server I have:

```
Meteor.publish('videosQue', function (room_id) {
  return Videos.find({room_id: room_id});
});
```

And on the client I set it up like the todo example:

```
var videosHandle = null;
Deps.autorun(function(){
  var room_id = Session.get('room_id');
  if (room_id)
    videosHandle = Meteor.subscribe('videosQue', room_id);
  else
    videosHandle = null;
});
```

And then here is some code that applies to when a person is in a room:

```
Template.EnteredRoom.loading = function () {
  return videosHandle && !videosHandle.ready();
};

Template.EnteredRoom.room = function () {
  return Rooms.findOne(Session.get('room_id'));
};

Template.EnteredRoom.video_objs = function () {
  Session.set('videos', Videos.findOne({room_id: Session.get('room_id')}))
  return Session.get('videos');
};

Template.EnteredRoom.rendered = function () {
  if (Session.get('videos') && Session.get('videos').videoIds.length) {
    var currVid = 0, playlist = Session.get('videos').videoIds;
    renderVid(playlist, currVid);
  };
};

var renderVid = function(playlist, currVid) {
  var video = Popcorn.youtube('#youtube-video', 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + playlist[currVid] + '&autoplay=1');

  video.on("ended", function() {
    if (++currVid < playlist.length) 
      renderVid(playlist, currVid);
    else {
      $('#youtube-video').hide();
      $('#video-container').append('<div style="font-size:30px;color:white;">No Videos :( Try adding one!</div>');
    }
  });
}
```

Is there anyway to get this done?

Thanks for the Help!

Andrew

EDIT: 
After doing some reading I think that I should somehow use isolate to achieve this, any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try putting the part that you don't need reactive in the {{#constant}} block.

```
{{#constant}}
    {{#each ...}}
    ....
    {{/each}}
{{/constant}}
```

I prefer to do it disable the reactive from collection with { reactive: false } option, in your model function:

```
    return collection.find({}, {reactive:false}) }
```